# How to get drywall to match up with backerboard when remodelling a tub surround when backerboard is proud of the drywall?

Tags: drywall, tile, transition

[image: Detail of the situation]Hey all and thanks for your potential help for myself and others that come across this issue.  I've been getting a lot of good info from this site and wanted to initiate a topic that I feel needs to be addressed.  I assume it must be a fairly common difficulty that comes up in bathroom remodels but doesn't have a clear solution to it.

The set up:
Old bathtub has been removed along with the drywall in the area around the tub.  Goal is to install a new tub, backer board, and then tile out just past the front of the tub to the existing 1/2" drywall.

The problem:  No easy way for adding backerboard over a tub flange that will then sit flush with drywall.

1. Framing for a standard bathtub leaves an opening between the studs of about 60 1/4", but the bathtub is only 60" long so here is our first 1/4" extra space.
2. Tub flange is 1/4" each side for an additional 1/2" extra space.
3. Let's add an 1/8" for the nail/screw heads holding the flange to the framing.
4. Total is 7/8", so at least a hair over 3/8" of extra space per side.  This could be more in areas depending on how straight your walls are.
5. Once you've installed your 1/2" backerboard properly over the flange (and not floating above the flange and caulked), you will now be at least 3/8"+ proud on both sides over any existing 1/2" drywall.

Is there a correct/elegant solution to this in a remodel situation?

Potential solutions I've considered:

1. Tear out all the drywall and fur out new drywall to match the backerboard.  Seems excessive and a tad wasteful if the current drywall, paint, etc. is in good condition.
2. Scrap the tub and just tile in a standalone shower.  By skipping the tub/flange business you would be able to bring the backerboard flush with the drywall.  Adds a lot of expense to the tile work, more difficult waterproofing/longevity for amateurs, and now there is no tub.
3. Float in the drywall to match the backer board.  I'm not the world's best drywaller, but an almost 1/2" float into a perfectly flat tile job must be noticeable in such a small/well lit area like a bathroom.
4. Leave the cement board proud, tile up to it, then use pencil or mud cap tile pieces to try and hide the gap discrepancy.  So far seems like the simplest solution, but has a few potential hazards.  Can you effectively tape and seal a cement board/drywall joint that is so far out of plane?  And then hope that these small tiles perfectly cover this gap without messing up your tile layout?

Comment: Why are you using 1/2" backerboard on the walls instead of 1/4"?

Comment: Is this an actual problem you're looking at right now or a theoretical/hypothetical one? [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." - hypothetical questions are explicitly off topic...

Comment: A diagram would help.   Not sure I understand the problem.  In general the interfaces between tiled walls and untiled walls are not flush, and there are all sorts of standard solutions but you seem to be describing something else.

Comment: @brhans It was my understanding that walls needed to be done in 1/2" cement board as only floors can use 1/4" since there is already a subfloor under them?

Comment: @FreeMan This is a real situation that I have been trying to work around.

Comment: @Fredric Shope Thanks, I had read that article.  Their problem is the opposite of the one I'm facing as they need to shim their backerboard out to match, while mine is already too far out.

Comment: Why tear out and fur out for new drywall instead of just laying another layer over the existing?

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to tape and mud the seam, easing the edge out 12 to 16 inches past the mating edges. Then tile past the edge of the tub by 2 to 5 inches using bullnose (not so common anymore) or aluminum trim such as Schluter Jolly.

Comment: Can you effectively tape the seam when the backerboard and drywall are 1/2" out of plane?  I added a diagram to my original post for clarification.

Comment: You can mud over much bigger problems than that, and sometimes you don't have a choice.  But IMO if you're already using a bullnose or metal trim, you may as well try to *entirely* deal with the problem that way.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you have five options:

1. Find a transition material to cover the offset.  Go to a large tile store and see what they have.  Edge tiles or variants of that, or metal edging.  There will be one section with metal strips and another with ceramic, stone and resin edge tiles.  Outside corner tiles, Bullnose tiles, etc.
2. (This is similar to #1) Miter a tile to cover the edge.  Treat the overhang (offset + tile cement + tile edge) as a tiny return wall, and cover it with your tile using miter cuts to join the corner.
3. Remove the drywall, shim it out to the level you want.
4. You show in your diagram a 1/2 inch offset .. so just put a second layer of 1/2 inch drywall over the existing.
5. Ok this is a little unorthodox but install a framed sliding shower door, and install the vertical pieces against the *drywall*, ending the tile job butt up against the door frame.  I haven't thought this through, it may not work ... usually the door frame is installed over the tiles that extend right to the edge of the tub.

Comment: #4 was my immediate thought.